# React-Router not rendering pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i got a navbar template from bootstrap and tried to configure react-router, the url changes but the pages aren't rendering not sure what if it has to do with my navbar or the router

```js
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/home";
import Aboutus from "./pages/Aboutus";
import Services from "./pages/services";
import PrivacyPolicy from "./pages/PrivacyPolicy";
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <Link className="nav-link" to="../pages/home.jsx">
          Graphic-Lab
        </Link>
          </ul>
      </nav>

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="./pages/home.jsx">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="./pages/Aboutus.jsx">
          <Aboutus />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: path should be a desired url: `/home` or `/aboutus`

Answer (score 0):

Attribute `path` of `Route` expects browser URL to match. Not path of file you want to display.

So it has to be something like this:

```js
<Route path="/something">
    <MyCoolComponent/>
</Route>
```

It renders `MyCoolComponent` for URL like `https://example.com/something`.

You can read `path` definition and see some example at the [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string-string).

Answer (score 0):

There don't need to use file extensions, because you make an SAP, the file extensions need when you render different HTML pages on different routes, but in React you just imitate the pages with JS. Just use `path="/home"` and `path="/about"`.